# Eliminate #Error when I run the code vba in ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I need help, because when I run de code, Error appears when some date field is empty. I have a table with information and I run this code since the generator.

Eliminate #Error when I run the code vba in ACCESS

I will grateful for you help.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function WorkingDays2(FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA As Date, FECHA_IMPRESIÓN As Date) As Integer
'....................................................................
' Name:     WorkingDays2
' Inputs:   StartDate As Date
'   EndDate As Date
' Returns: Integer
' Author: Arvin Meyer
' Date:     May 5,2002
' Comment: Accepts two dates and returns the number of weekdays between them
' Note that this function has been modified to account for holidays. It requires a table
' named tblHolidays with a field named HolidayDate.
'....................................................................

Dim intCount As Integer
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim DB As DAO.Database

Set DB = CurrentDb
Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT [DIAFESTIVO] FROM DIASFESTIVOS", dbOpenSnapshot)

'StartDate = StartDate + 1
'To count StartDate as the 1st day comment out the line above

intCount = 0

Do While FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA <= FECHA_IMPRESIÓN

rst.FindFirst "[DIAFESTIVO] = #" & FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA & "#"
If Weekday(FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA) <> vbSunday And Weekday(FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA) <> vbSaturday Then
If rst.NoMatch Then intCount = intCount + 1
End If

FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA = FECHA_DE_VALIDACION_FA + 1



Loop

WorkingDays2 = intCount

Exit_WorkingDays2:
Exit Function

WorkingDays2 = intCount

Exit_WorkingDays2:
Exit Function

Err_WorkingDays2:
Select Case Err

Case Else
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_WorkingDays2
End Select


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit where you are calling this function from within your database. Probably as a calculated field in a query? Something like this: 
`WorkingDays: WorkingDays3([YourDateField])`?

Try this instead:
`WorkingDays: WorkingDays3(Nz([YourDateField],Date())`

Answer (score 0):

Your original question included code for a function named WorkingDays3, which takes one date parameter.

Your illustration shows a function named WorkingDays2, which takes two date parameters.

I think you will need to give more detailed information about the data you are working with, and under which conditions you are seeing the #Error.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now.  And now, could you give some example of what circumstances you see the #Error in your query?

Comment: For example, is it when there is no data in one of the 2 date fields in the table that you base your query on?